# Multiple select in Report Builder 3

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportbuilder3.0

I have created a parameter that gives multiple options to the user:

```
Total Amount = Grand Total
Region 1 = Total Amount for that Region
Region 2 = Total Amount for that Region
Region 3 = Total Amount for that Region
Region 4 = Total Amount for that Region
```

Region 1 to 4 works great but when I select the Total Amount  I get the incorrect amount.

Can some one tell me what I am doing wrong please.

Main Dataset

```
     SELECT       OccupancyDetail.CalendarYear, OccupancyDetail.CalendarMonth, SUM(OccupancyDetail.No_of_Nights) AS No_of_Nights, 
                         SUM(OccupancyDetail.Capacity) AS Capacity,Site.BDM,Site.Region
FROM            OccupancyDetail INNER JOIN
                         Site ON OccupancyDetail.Site_Skey = Site.Site_Skey

                         WHERE  (OccupancyDetail.ReferenceDate = convert(Date,getdate()))

                         AND
                         CASE WHEN @Time = 'YEAR' THEN CAST(CalendarYear as varchar(4)) else
                         CalendarMonth + ' ' + CAST(CalendarYear as varchar(4)) end in (@Dates)
GROUP BY OccupancyDetail.ReferenceDate, OccupancyDetail.CalendarYear, OccupancyDetail.CalendarMonth,Site.BDM, Site.Region    
Time Dataset

select DateChoice FROM
(select distinct CalendarYear, 1 as MonthNumber,CAST(CalendarYear as varchar(4)) as DateChoice from Time
where @Time = 'YEAR'


union all

select Distinct CalendarYear, MonthNumber,CalendarMonth + ' ' + CAST(CalendarYear as varchar(4)) as DateChoice from Time where @Time = 'MONTH') as QRYDATA
ORDER BY CalendarYear,MonthNumber
```

BDM Dataset

```
SELECT DISTINCT BDM
FROM Site
```

Comment: Can you make an example?

Answer (score 0):

Reporting Services parameters provide a built-in `(Select All)` value when multiple value parameters are defined.

[image: Select All Parameters]

For your example:

1. Remove the `Total Amount = Grand Total` option from the available values list in the parameter.
2. Modify your dataset query to accept multiple values for the region parameter. For example: `... WHERE REGION IN (@Region)`
3. Check the `Allow multiple values` option in parameter properties
   [image: Multiple value parameters]
4. `(Select All)` replaces the `Total Amount = Grand Total` from your original design.

Comment: Hi Beargle

I allow multiple values as above, I get my available values from a Query, this has Region 1, Region 2 etc but when I tick Select All it gives me the result of of Region 1 instead.

Thanks

Comment: @wafw1971 Check step 3 in the answer above. Please edit your question and post the query used in the dataset.

Comment: I have done step 3 no change, I have copied my datasets above as per request.

Comment: @wafw1971 Where is the region filter? It's not in the main dataset. Post some sample data if you want a more complete answer.

Comment: I haven't started that yet.

Calendar Year Calendar Month No_of_Nights Capacity     BDM
2011               April         104647      300720    Jim White
2011               April         128496      422820   Mary Peacock
2011               April         103605      333510    Roger Green
2011               April         92133       263310    Sam Scarlett

Comment: @wafw1971 You'll have to add the region filter to the main dataset to accomplish your original goal. Your region parameter selection will have no impact on report output until that is done.

Comment: Sorry Beargle, I have not explained myself clearly (I am new to this as you can tell) When I use my BDM Parameter and select 1 BDM the correct figures appear however if I select more than 1 BDM or Select All then only the first BDMs results show. I want them to add up.

Comment: @wafw1971 The previous comment stands. It appears region = `BDM`. The main dataset query posted does not filter results by `BDM`.

Comment: I have added the Region to the Dataset (See Above), what do I do now?

Comment: @wafw1971 As stated previously, the region filter should be part of the `WHERE` clause. My advice is to start over, get the SQL query right, then incorporate into the report.

Comment: Thanks Beargle, I'm sorry I didn't read your second point correctly, I thought you said to modify my BDM Dataset. I will start over.